# All Application Pools time out, but not one

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, iis, iis-7.5

I am debugging in Visual Studio 2010 with IIS 7.5. I have four enabled AppPools. This is on my development machine, so no one else accesses it, at all.

So the problem is that three of these AppPools time out, but forth one doesn't. I am not bothered why this one stays there, but more concerned why the other three time out, as I use them more often.

I have checked all settings for them and they match exactly. I can certainly increase "Idle Time-out" settings but wanted to know what is causing it.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out the reason. But as a workaround, I set "Idle Time-out (minutes" property to 60 and it is working out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Disable pinging (set **Ping Enabled** to **false**). When it's turned on, IIS hosting proces checks constantly (every 30s) if a pool process is alive. If a given application pool process does not respond withing a predefined period (**Ping Maximum Response Time** = 90s) it is restarted. I can't tell exactly why one pool is not restarted - maybe while debugging it was responding to IIS pings.